# Convergence of series of random variables with hypothesis over a specific series

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm studying from Resnick's *A Probability Path*, and I'm facing the following problem: suppose that $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of independent random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=0$ for all $n$. I need to show that $\sum_n X_n$ converges almost surely if
$$\sum_n \mathbb{E} \left( X_n^2 \mathbf{1}_{[|X_n|\leq 1]} + |X_n|\mathbf{1}_{[|X_n|>1]} \right) < \infty.$$
The problem provides the hint: $0 = \mathbf{E}(X_n) = \mathbf{E}(X_n\mathbf{1}_{[|X_n|\leq 1]}) + \mathbf{E}(X_n\mathbf{1}_{[|X_n|> 1]})$.

I thought I could use the Kolmogorov Three Series Theorem, but I don't see how to use it.

Any help or hint will be useful. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three Series is not necessary here, but One Series might help. By the monotone convergence theorem,

$$\mathbb E\left(\sum_n|X_n|\mathbf1_{[|X_n|>1]}\right) =\sum_n\mathbb E(|X_n|\mathbf1_{[|X_n|>1]})<\infty$$

and hence $\sum_n|X_n|\mathbf1_{[|X_n|>1]}<\infty$ almost surely. This implies that, with probability one, $|X_n|>1$ for at most finitely many $n$. It thus suffices to show $\sum_n Y_n$ converges, where $Y_n=X_n\mathbf1_{[|X_n|\le1]}$. Are you able to finish it off?

Comment: I have two observations:

(1) In your answer, to which series are you referring to? Because you mixed the $X_n^2$ with the indicator of the other series.

(2) What happens if I use the same argument you used (MCT for series) in both series? With one I'll get a set with prob. 1 where $|X_n|>1$ for at most finitely many $n$, and with the other a set with prob. 1 where $|X_n|\leq 1$ for finitely many $n$. Can I intersect both sets and conclude?

Comment: You're right, I used the wrong series. I have edited now. The conclusion is the same - $|X_n|>1$ for at most finitely many $n$, with probably one. You can't do this for the $[|X_n|\le1]$ series, since $\sum_n|a_n|\mathbf1_{[|a_n|\le1]}$ can converge without only finitely many terms being nonzero.

Comment: Thank you both for the hint and for the clarification. I could finish it off!